# PY2EXE and SELENIUM ISSUE

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, py2exe

After reading all posts about it, i still don't understand why my exe isn't working.....

This is my "setup.py" :

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

wd_path = 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver'
required_data_files = [('selenium/webdriver/firefox',
                    ['{}\\firefox\\x86\\x_ignore_nofocus.so'.format(wd_path), '{}\\firefox\\amd64\\x_ignore_nofocus.so'.format(wd_path)]),('selenium/webdriver/remote',['{}\\remote\\getAttribute.js'.format(wd_path),'{}\\remote\\isDisplayed.js'.format(wd_path)])]

setup(
windows = [{'script': "autovote.py"}],
dll_excludes=['msvcr71.dll', "IPHLPAPI.DLL", "NSI.dll",  "WINNSI.DLL",  "WTSAPI32.dll"],
data_files = required_data_files,
name = "AutoVote 100% Naruto",
version="1.0",
description = "AutoVote 100% Naruto V1.0 réalisé par GARBEZ François contact:fgarbez-dev@netcourrier.com",
options = {
           "py2exe":{
                     "bundle_files": 1,
                     "compressed":1,
                    }
           }
)
```

This is the error.log :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "autovote.py", line 4, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "selenium\webdriver\__init__.pyc", line 18, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.pyc", line 34, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyc", line 25, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.pyc", line 40, in <module>
File "pkgutil.pyc", line 591, in get_data
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'
```

But i have all my files in my dist\selenium\webdriver... As it is created when compiling... I tried PYInstaller too, that one didn't work at all... I tried almost EVERYTHING i saw on the same topics...Nothing can solve it T.T

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I remade my setup.py :

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

wd_path = 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver'
required_data_files = [('selenium/webdriver/firefox',
                    ['{}\\firefox\\x86\\x_ignore_nofocus.so'.format(wd_path), '{}\\firefox\\amd64\\x_ignore_nofocus.so'.format(wd_path)]),('selenium/webdriver/remote',['{}\\remote\\getAttribute.js'.format(wd_path),'{}\\remote\\isDisplayed.js'.format(wd_path)])]

setup(
windows = [{'script': "autovote.py"}],
name = "AutoVote 100% Naruto",
version="1.0",
description = "AutoVote 100% Naruto V1.0 réalisé par GARBEZ François contact:fgarbez-dev@netcourrier.com",
dll_excludes=['msvcr71.dll', "IPHLPAPI.DLL", "NSI.dll",  "WINNSI.DLL",  "WTSAPI32.dll"],
data_files = required_data_files,
options = {
           "py2exe":{ 
                     "skip_archive": True,
                    }
           }
)
```

The only difference is that i took off :

```
'zipfile':None,
```

and

```
'bundle_files':1,
```

Now it's working....Well i still don't get it but at least it works :)

Comment: Could someone explain to me, please ?